# Reinstall deb package from another release

Tags: package, ansible, version, apt

I need reinstall package from another target release. Problem is that if package is already installed no action is taken. My ansible playbook fragment is:

```
- name: Add jessie-backports repo
  apt_repository:
    repo: 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main'
    state: present

- name: install libssl from jessie-backports
  apt:
    name: libssl1.0.0
    default_release: jessie-backports
```

and ansible answer is:

```
ptmp3 | SUCCESS => {
    "cache_update_time": 1493744770, 
    "cache_updated": true, 
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        ....
    }
}
```

I can remove old version before installing new, but whole bunch of packages depends on `libssl` (`ssh` for example).

Btw command `apt-get install libssl1.0.0 -t jessie-backports` at remote host works, and libssl is updated

Comment: Why there is no state=present in you apt task ?

Comment: state= present is default value

Comment: Have you tried using `force: true` with the apt module ?

Comment: yes, i have tried

Comment: Try 'dpkg_options: force-downgrade' along with 'force: true'

Comment: no. This option don't work also. If I understand - ansible check if package is installed and if yes omit `apt-get` command (that is why `default_release`, and `dpkg_options` options are ignored)

Comment: Use APT pinning, see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/800727/puppet-how-to-honor-install-options-of-package-if-specific-package-is-install) for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to include exact version of package to be installed in apt task. Exact version can be retrieved by `apt-cache` (`apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0`).

Appropriate chunk of playbook would be:

```
- name: Add jessie-backports repo
  apt_repository:
    update_cache: yes
    repo: 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main'
    state: present

- name: get libssl1.0.0 jessie-backports version
  shell: apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0 | grep jessie-backports -B1 | head -n1 | sed -e 's/^\s*\**\s*\(\S*\).*/\1/'
  register: libsslinstalled

- name: install libssl from jessie-backports
  apt:
    name: "libssl1.0.0={{ libsslinstalled.stdout_lines[0] }}"
```